# Debugging a Spring DSL

Tags: debugging

I am new to Camel . I am using RED HAT JBOSS Fuse which uses Sprig DSL in my implementation .
Is there a way to debug the DSL or the camel-context.xml in the eclipse editor ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps in the below link to install the plugin into eclipse:

http://lhein.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-install-jboss-fuse-tooling-into.html